# Can I continue after the last mission?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

After completing the last story mission - does the game 'end' or am I allowed to continue playing, hunting achievements, etc?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  As soon as the final mission is over, you can return to the island and complete any achievements or missions you might have missed.

Answer (score 1):

On the one hand, yes, you can keep playing once you beat the game.

On the other hand, for the most part, nothing respawns, so while you can run around and shoot your shiny high-end guns a whole lot, there really just isn't much to *do*.

Unless of course, you're playing on the PC and not averse to some .dll editing.

The full method is outlined in [this forum post.](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/739422-MOD-Enemy-retake-the-Islands-experimental!) It will reset all of the outposts, giving you plenty of new bad guys to shoot in a variety of exciting and badass ways.

To do this, you'll first want to make a backup of the target file, either FC3.dll or FC3_d3d11.dll (which is tied to your DirectX version of choice). Once you've done that, open the original in a Hex Editor. You'll want to find

```
55 6E 6C 6F 63 6B 65 64 57 6F 72 6C 64 4D 61 70 49 74 65 6D 73
```

and replace it with

```
4E 6F 6C 6F 63 6B 65 64 57 6F 72 6C 64 4D 61 70 49 74 65 6D 73
```

and save the modified .dll.

Then open the game, load your save, and save the game and quit. Then restore the original .dll from your backup, and start up the game. You should now have many new mans to shoot.

Comment: That Ubisoft forum post seems to be about Far Cry 3. Can you confirm if it also works for FC3: Blood Dragon?

Comment: @Galacticninja I can.

Comment: I noticed that you said that through some .dll editing you can revert all of the outposts, is it possible to do the same in order to replay the final mission? Or is there some other way to do so without having to do all of the missions over again?