# What is there to do in the post-game?

Tags: far-cry-3-blood-dragon

I've cleared all the sidequests in *Blood Dragon* before taking on the last missions. Walking around a bit in the post-game, I don't see anything to do. Are there any post-game missions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I continue after the last mission?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/116923/can-i-continue-after-the-last-mission)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz it's not though, is it? That question is asking if you're able to play after the end of the story, this question is about whether there is anything to play after the end of the story.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I know I can continue, I'm just asking **"Is there anything to do?"**.

Comment: @Cyberskull you might be interested in my answer to the other linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. That option is really only their if you were missing side missions. All you can really do now is run around.

Comment: And complete the achievements! On a side note, I feel bad for people who completed the side-quests without the Arm Laser shooting weapon, that thing just annihilates people.